# How to increase the memory used by Java in linux?

Tags: fedora, memory, java, application, out-of-memory

I have a program Vuze that is written in Java, which I use to download very large files, and I'm having a problem with it. I need to increase the amount of memory it uses. I've followed the directions for the application but it doesn't change the real memory usage. I would think this would then be because Java (JVM) is not set to support the amount of memory I set in the application.

I both get errors about files missing and low memory.

How can I increase the memory used by my Java Virtual Machine?

My Java is Oracle. My system is Fedora 20 X86_64 KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem [here](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Too_many_open_files).

The workaround: I increased the memory used to 1024M with [these](http://wiki.vuze.com/w/Java_VM_memory_usage) instructions.
I set the "Maximum files opened for read/write" to a 101.
I ran the application from the command line with this command:

```
sudo bash -c 'ulimit -n 8192'; sudo -u username ./azureus
```

Comment: I set Vuze to run a different Java when I run it with this command from the commandline, the memory usage was unchanged if launch it with the application launcher.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to modify the vuze shell script. This shell script is actually a link to a file called `azureus`, vuze's previous name. Within this script change the line `JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx128m"` to `JAVA_ARGS="-Xmx256m"`, for example if you want to increase the memory to 256MB. Then restart vuze

Comment: do you see that message on console output when you run that `sh ./azureus` script?

Comment: The messages are a Vuze messages. They come in the lower right corner of the application.